# How to clone extjs store and use it for multiple grids

Tags: extjs, clone, store, extjs4.2

How can i use same store(with different filters) for multiple grids having same column structure?

I have used store.filter() method and passed the filtered store to the grid but since only the reference of filtered store is getting passed, all grids are showing same data.

Tried Ext.clone() with no luck

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the problems that the framework really haven't solved in ExtJs 4.x But they have specific support for it in ExtJs 5. If possible you may want to consider upgrading.

If not, you could request the data from the server by ajax, and then use json result to fill data to all the stores. Using this method you can will several stores, with the same data, with only a single server request.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to create separate instances of the same store class in grid `initComponent` override - no need for clones then.

You can see this approach [here](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#writable-grid)

Comment: with respect to the specified example, How can i use multiple instances of 'CompanyStore' with multiple instances of 'maingridview' ?

Comment: The key is that you create the instance of `CompanyStore` in `initComponent` of `maingridview`. initComponent runs when the grid is instantiated so the store is also instantiated at this time. You would do the same in all views that use this store.